# How can I get all the two-way bindings present in an Angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get a list of all the two-way bindings that exist in a given template? Ideally it would be limited to only bindings that bind to a `form.result` object property or one of its nested objects/arrays.

My first attempt was to use regular expressions, but there are just too many variations to contend with that are giving me false positives.

```
$http.get(templateFile).then(function (response) {
    var ngModelRegex = /="[^"]*(form\.result[^"\[]*)[^"]*"/gi;
    var bindings = [];

     var match = ngModelRegex.exec(response.data);
     while (match != null) {
         bindings.push(match[1]);
         match = ngModelRegex.exec(response.data);
     };
     console.log(templateFile, bindings);
 });
```

It must be possible because Angular is able to do it, so how can I do the same? Using `$compile` possibly?